# yum update kernel conflict

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, fedora, yum, raspberry-pi

I have RaspberryPI model B with Fedora Raspberry Remix 17 RC2 (installed at September 2012).
Yesterday, i did try yum update. But i could not do it. Why?

```
[root@rberry ~]# yum update raspberrypi-kernel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package raspberrypi-kernel.armv5tel 0:3.2.27-1.20120926git9245b4c.rpfr17 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================
Package Arch Version Repository Size
============================================================================
Installing:
raspberrypi-kernel armv5tel 3.2.27-1.20120926git9245b4c.rpfr17 rasp-pi 12 M

Transaction Summary
============================================================================
Install 1 Package

Total size: 12 M
Installed size: 37 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running Transaction Check
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
file /boot/kernel.img from install of raspberrypi-kernel-3.2.27-1.20120926git9245b4c.rpfr17.armv5tel conflicts with file from package raspberrypi-kernel-3.1.9-11.20120727gitf958199.rpfr17.armv5tel

Error Summary
-------------
```

Update

```
[root@rberry opt]# rpm -qa raspberrypi-kernel\*
raspberrypi-kernel-3.1.9-11.20120727gitf958199.rpfr17.armv5tel

[root@rberry opt]# uname -a
Linux rberry 3.1.9 #1 PREEMPT Mon Jul 30 14:50:41 EDT 2012 armv6l armv6l armv6l GNU/Linux

[root@rberry opt]# yum install raspberrypi-kernel-3.2.27-1.20120926git9245b4c.rpfr17.armv5tel
.....
Transaction Check Error:
  file /boot/kernel.img from install of raspberrypi-kernel-3.2.27-1.20120926git9245b4c.rpfr17.armv5tel conflicts with file from package raspberrypi-kernel-3.1.9-11.20120727gitf958199.rpfr17.armv5tel

[root@rberry opt]# rpm -qf /boot/kernel.img
raspberrypi-kernel-3.1.9-11.20120727gitf958199.rpfr17.armv5tel
```

Sorry for my bad English ))

Comment: Where did you find Fedora Raspberry Remix 17 RC2?

Comment: http://scotland.proximity.on.ca/raspberrypi/test-releases/raspberrypi-fedora-remix-17/latest/rpfr-17-xfce-RC2.zip

Comment: http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_Fedora_Remix_17

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

There likely is a packaging problem in which both kernel packages "owns" a common set of files (in this case, `/boot/kernel.img` is claimed by both packages, ergo they cannot both be installed at the same time)

What kernels do you have installed at the moment? Try

```
rpm -qa raspberry-kernel\*
```

If you have another kernel beside the `3.1.9-11` that's causing the problem, boot to it, remove the troublesome one and then install the new kernel update.

Failing that, just update everything but the kernel:

```
yum update --exclude=raspberry-kernel\*
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

> yum clean all

followed by

> yum update

I got the same problem and solved it in a minute. Hope it can still be helpful.